# Change String Value in tmp Folder Using Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

Here I tried below code to write string value in tmp Folder. I used FromAsciiString() and ToAsciiString() for read/write value. Here I print m.ReadString if Read String value is Successful. I store string successful. But I required to change string value. Is It possible using roByteArray?

```
m.LocalFile = CreateObject("roByteArray")
m.LocalFile.FromAsciiString("Nikunj Chaklasiya")
    
m.ReadString = m.LocalFile.ToAsciiString()  
    
?"ReadString: " m.ReadString
    
m.LocalFile.WriteFile("tmp:/interlink")
m.LocalFile.ReadFile("tmp:/interlink")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read file, convert it to string, update it and then write back to file.

Here you write to the file at first time

```
LocalFile = CreateObject("roByteArray")
LocalFile.FromAsciiString("Nikunj Chaklasiya")
ReadString = LocalFile.ToAsciiString()  
?"ReadString: " ReadString
LocalFile.WriteFile("tmp:/interlink")
```

if you want to update string later some there else in the code, do that

```
LocalFile = CreateObject("roByteArray")
LocalFile.ReadFile("tmp:/interlink")
ReadString = LocalFile.ToAsciiString()
ReadString = ReadString + "_updated"
?"ReadString updated: " ReadString
LocalFile.FromAsciiString(ReadString)
LocalFile.WriteFile("tmp:/interlink")
```